# E: Unable to locate package mssql-server-is

Tags: ssis, ubuntu-20.04

During to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu) I've tried to install SSID on Ubuntu 20.04. Does Microsoft support SSID on Ubuntu 20.04?
As I see [here](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/) we're able to find package for this version.

Any ideas why I can't install it?

```sh
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0   4964      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4964
OK
```

```sh
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 focal main
```

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server-is
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mssql-server-is
```

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is that you follow the exact instructions form Microsoft installation web https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16

Here is used the command for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"
```